# Implementing string search functionality in django

Tags: django, forms, list, search

I am trying to implement a search functionality in django that filters a list of records based on a string, same as the one that present in `django admin list filtering`

But here we are not going to filter the results `from the database` based on the query string got from search form, instead we need to `filter from the list` that i have already

**views.py**

```
def filter_contacts(request):
    contacts = ['None <steve.one@gmail.com>', 'None <ronold@gmail.com>', 
               'None <jacksparrow@gmail.com>', 'None <dude@gmail.com>' ...... up to more than 1000]
    if request.GET:
        if request.GET.has_key('q'):
            contacts = **filter the contacts from the above list that contains query string "q" and create a new list**
        else:
            contacts = contacts
    return render_to_response('social_feeds/gmail_contacts.html', {'contacts':contacts})
```

**search_form something like**

```
<form class="form-search" action="{% url 'contacts' %}" method="get">
      <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" class="span2 search-query" name="q" value="" id="searchbar">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search">Search</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

Of course we can filter the `query string` from the list by `looping` and searching the string in each and every string in the list and if it has create a new list,

but since/suppose we have more than 1000 strings(emails probably as above), that process should be `very/ultimately` fast, so looking for the `functionality/process/method` that filters the list very fast based on the `query paramerter` like suppose

if we search the form with `steve`, all the `strings/emails` that contains `steve` should be filtered in to a new list, and thats what i am looking for

can any one please let me know how to implement searching functionality very fast ?

Comment: what you are looking for is `autocomplete`. There is lots of documentation out there. There is also a 3rd party app called `django-autocomplete` which might interest you

Comment: @karthikr: But what when i want the results to be filtered only after hitting the search button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way would be to have the emails **in a database**, and then use a query to fetch them. Something like this:

models.py

```
class Contact(models.model):
    email = models.EmailField()
```

and then in views.py:

```
if request.GET.has_key('q'):
    query = request.GET['q']
    contacts = Contact.objects.all().filter(email__contains=query)
```

Failing that, you want to use a pythonic way. There are probably faster ways out there than simply looping, but then again, looping isn't that slow as you might think. I took a 60k email list ([this one!](http://www.mediafire.com/download/bfb7txj4p2fodqw/60.000+Hotmail.gmail.yahoo+maillist.txt)), and looped over it in the so-called "slow method" like so:

```
f = open('maillist.txt', 'rb')
lines = f.readlines()
res = []
for l in lines:
    if 'steve' in l:
        res.append(l)
```

And timing it showed it took about 0.008 seconds to complete.

Just to show how fast the 'simple' approaches might be, I timed different methods of achieving the same result:

```
timing = {}
res = []
import time

# normal iteration
start = time.time()
for l in lines:
    if 'steve' in l:
        res.append(l)
end = time.time()
timing['iteration'] = end-start
length = len(res)


res = []
# list comprehension
start = time.time()
[res.append(l) for l in lines if 'steve' in l]
end = time.time()
timing['list comprehension'] = end-start
assert(len(res) == length)

#
def search(s):
    res =[]
    if 'steve' in s:
        res.append(s)
    return res

# built in 'filter' method
start = time.time()
res = filter(search, lines)
end = time.time()
timing['filter'] = end-start
assert(len(res) == length)

#using itertools
import itertools
start = time.time()
res = itertools.ifilter(search, lines)
end = time.time()
timing['ifilter'] = end-start

for key, value in timing.iteritems():
    print key, value, 'seconds'
```

lines being a list of the aforementioned 60k email list, the results where as following:

```
iteration                  0.00799989700317 seconds
list comprehension         0.00699996948242 seconds
filter                     0.0130000114441 seconds
ifilter                    0.0 seconds
```

As you can see, the fastest way would be to use list comprehension. This was for calculating if 'steve' was in the email, but if you do something a little more complicated, like if 'steve' is in email or 'smith' is in email than the results change a little:

```
iteration                  0.0139999389648 seconds
list comprehension         0.010999917984 seconds
filter                     0.0169999599457 seconds
ifilter                    0.0 seconds
```

Still, list comprehension is the winner. You might be wondering why ifilter takes 0 time, but it's simple - ifilter creates a generator. Loading the results dynamically could prove efficient for your needs.

In any way, as you can clearly see, the differences between all those version is in miliseconds. I can't imagine you need anything faster than that, but you should test and time different methods and if you find that you somehow still need something more, just go to pypi and look for a package that allows fast filtering.

Comment: Actually i will get those list of emails from `gmail`(something like importing contacts from gmail), so there is no way that i can save them all in to database, i will get emails on the fly, and need to filter the list based on query string when user entered some word in search form

Comment: I expanded my answer a little. Hope this helps